# integrating an Intranet Web app with QB Online

Tags: integration, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Our company currently uses Web Connector to allow our operational application (web-based) to interact with a desktop QB Pro data file.

We want to investigate Quickbooks Online as a replacement for QB Pro.  We only want to create a 'One-off' solution peculiar to us and similar to what we do now with web connector.

This solution would be an app, I guess.

Do we have to 'publish' our app in order to use it, even though it's for our company use only? Are there fees to publish.  Can you publish something for your own use only?

Also, can the connection between our web app and the QB Online data base be automated or does each user need to log in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we have to 'publish' our app in order to use it, even though it's for our company use only?

No.

You an also "private publish" which is as easy as just sending Intuit an e-mail.

> Are there fees to publish?

No.

> Can you publish something for your own use only?

Yes. Private publish.

> Also, can the connection between our web app and the QB Online data base be automated or does each user need to log in some way?

The connection is not user-based at all. Your QuickBooks administrator will authorize access once, and then from there on out it's all automated/programatic/no logins required.